# Troubleshooting Subsetting within Function in R

Tags: r, parameter-passing, subset

I'm creating a function that subsets a dataframe by a unique facility ID. The subsetting works when I directly define the character string:

```
facility<-ECHO_2010_2017[ECHO_2010_2017$Facility.ID=="VA0004090",]
```

But when I try to pass a parameter through, it maintains the original data frame:

```
Facility.ID="VA0004090"
facility<-ECHO_2010_2017[ECHO_2010_2017$Facility.ID==Facility.ID,]
```

Any ideas of why this passing would cause the subset to fail?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please make a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because the variable name is identical to the column name try
`fac_id ="VA0004090"
facility <- ECHO_2010_2017[Facility.ID == fac_id, ]`

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you.